# Letting SKSpriteNode go out of the screen

Tags: sprite-kit

I am developing a multiplayer game in which each player is represented by an object of class SKSpriteNode.

It is a platform game in which players run to the right till they reach the end of the world.

The problem is that the players are unfortunately caged in the visible area of the screen, and not matter how I try, they do not seem to like leaving it. That is what I am trying to solve right now.

The way this multiplayer mode works is that a player can be behind or in front of the other player, and this can happen outside of the visible area in the screen. All players are affected by physics (specially gravity)

The code that creates the physicsBody of a player is the following:

```
player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:player.size.width/2];
[player.physicsBody setDensity:100];
[player.physicsBody setCategoryBitMask:kPlayerCategory];
[player.physicsBody setContactTestBitMask:kWallCategory | kGroundCategory];
[player.physicsBody setCollisionBitMask:kWallCategory | kGroundCategory];
[player.physicsBody setAffectedByGravity:YES];
```

As I said, sometimes the opponent player has to leave the visible area, but it looks like if it crashes against the edges of the screen.

A workaround I wrote is to change the opponent's physicsBody to bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect. That creates a physic body with the dynamic property set to NO. It is an ugly hack and it does not work very well since gravity stops affecting it.

```
    CGPoint leftCorner = [self.scene convertPoint:CGPointZero toNode:camera];
    if (_playerOponent.position.x <= leftCorner.x+30) {
        _playerOponent.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:_playerOponent.frame];
    } else if (_playerOponent.physicsBody != _playerOponentBody) {
        _playerOponent.physicsBody = _playerOponentBody;
    }
```

Ideally what I would need is to be able to have a scene with physics applied to it that is bigger than the screen size, so that there is the illusion that the opponent is moving in and out of the screen (imagine super mario 2d in multiplayer mode)

Thanks for helping out with this.

Comment: Unless you set up this "cage" yourself (ie with bodyWithEdgeLoop using the view's size) nothing will keep physics bodies inside the screen automatically. Check your code for any edge bodies you create, perhaps you simply need to change your map's border dimensions to that of the world rather than the view?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am just having an SKNode which is my world but I am not creating any edge bodies. How would it be possible to change the map border's dimensions?

Comment: myWorld = [SKNode node];
      [self addChild:myWorld];
      camera = [SKNode node];
      camera.name = @"camera";
      [myWorld addChild:camera];
This is how I am creating the nodes in which I am adding all the elements of the game. The camera is used to follow the character the user is currently playing.

Comment: Actually the bodies are caged in the screen when they are affected by physics, created by bodyWithCircleOfRadius (dynamic property == yes). Otherwise they are not.

Answer (score 0):

LearnCocos2D was right, I had set up a cage around my scene.

```
    CGRect bodyRect = CGRectMake(-size.width, -size.height, size.width*3, size.height*3);
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:bodyRect];
```

That would do the trick!